# Quotient Topology uniquely satisfies its characteristic property

Tags: general-topology

The characteristic property for a quotient topology $T_q$ induced by a surjective map $q: X \mapsto Y$ on  $Y$ states that a map $f: Y \mapsto Z$, $Z$ a topological space, is continuous  if and only if $f\circ q : X \mapsto Z$ is continuous.

Now suppose $T_s$ is a topology on $Y$ that satisfies the characteristic property. Then the identity map $id_{sq}:(Y,T_s) \mapsto (Y,T_q)$ is continuous because $q_q = id_{sq}\circ q_{s}: X \mapsto (Y,T_q)$ is continuous. This means that $T_q \subseteq T_s$ and therefore $(Y,T_q)$ is a subspace of $(Y,T_s)$; from this we know that the inclusion map $\iota: (Y,T_q) \mapsto (Y,T_s)$ is continuous, but since $\iota$ is simply the identity $id_{qs}: (Y,T_q) \mapsto (Y,T_s)$, we can finally conclude that both $id_{qs}$ and $id_{sq}$ are continuous and so $T_s = T_q$.

Though this question has been asked before, I had a slightly different proof for it (specifically the use of the subspace property) and was hoping it could be verified. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(Y, T_q)$ is not a subspace of $(Y, T_s)$: in general $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a subspace of $(X,\mathcal{T}')$ iff $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}'$ (because of the same $X$), and you haven't shown that. The identity being continuous means exactly an inclusion between topologies, not a "subspace relation". Because we can do it two ways by symmetry, we get two inclusions, hence equality.